# HTML/CSS Margin a paragraph with image

Tags: html, css, image, padding, margin

I want to add some margin/padding but keep the paragraph nice/clean and responsive.

I tried adding `margin: 10px` but it only applies to the first line

[image]

Is there a way to tune up the code above to have some padding/margin without compromising responsiveness.

Please be advised that **I cannot use** any JQUERY/Javascript in the code above due to clients odd restrictions.

```html
   <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ieffVLU.png" width="360px" style="float:left;border: 1px solid black">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5 style="text-align: justify;">
                            <span style="font-weight: normal;">
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something
                            </span>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: add the margin to the image

Comment: @TemaniAfif haha I'm laughing hard, I'm not sure why i didnt think of that at all, thank you very much, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add "display: block" to your image tag
and the output would be like:

```html
   <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ieffVLU.png" width="360px" style="float:left;border: 1px solid black; display:block">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5 style="text-align: justify;">
                            <span style="font-weight: normal;">
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something 
                                a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something a nice paragraph about something
                            </span>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change first div's width from 100% to 360px. Also, remove the extra div that came inside the first div. And if this not works, then insert span of second div to first div after the img.